# Have the parent execute something while waiting for child

Tags: python

I am trying to have two things execute at the same time. I have some code to run a PWM module, and I have some code to read from an ADC and both work. I want to now read from the ADC while waiting for the pwm module to finish. I thought of forking, but wasn't sure how to get the parent to wait for the child to finish.

I'd like to have something like the following:

```
pid = os.fork()
if(pid > 0):
     while(child not done):
         adc code 
else:
    pwm code
```

Comment: Threading? I think this is too broad/vague, can you be more specific? Have you looked at any resources on the subject?

Answer (score 1):

Using multiprocessing I was able to do it.

```
pwm_p = Process(target=my_pwm, args=(my_args,))
pmw_p.start()
while(pwm_p.is_alive()):
    read_from_adc()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `os.wait()` from the parent process to wait for the child to terminate. You can find an example of this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-wait-method/).

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted but I think I've figured it out